# how to run a function only once in javascript on every reload/refresh

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to load a function only once on first ever reload/refresh and other function to execute on every reload/refresh.

**this is how it should look**

```
var my_Var = set_Interval(my_Timer, 7000);

function my_Timer()
{
   location.reload();       
}
function to_Execute_Once()
{
}
function to_Execute_Every_Time()
{
}
```

Comment: When a page loads it knows nothing about the previous session, unless you pass some sort of parameter(s) or call an external source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
var isFirstLoad = localStorage.getItem('isFirstLoad');

if (!isFirstLoad) {
 to_Execute_Once()
 localStorage.setItem('isFirstLoad', 'true');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use localStorage(). On very first load of page set method execution variable in localStorage() and on successive reloads you can handle your function call based on that execution variable present in localStorage.